# hundreds of CLOSE_WAIT connections are eating away my ThreadPools

Tags: java, tcp, jboss, wait

we have a very cruel situation. We have a site in germany which is an online shop. Multiple times a day we are having huge number of connections in CLOSE_WAIT states showing up in netstat from one and the same ip. It's different IPs but they are all in china. 
We do have chinese customers still. 
Checking the access logs, we see that the traffic from the ip in questions comes from one browser (useragent, session id), but it doesn't look like real traffic, for example requesting the / 500 times in a row, without requesting css,js,images behind it. 
So what we end up with is having like 1000 threads in socketWrite0, from which 820 would be tied to same ip:

```
"http--0.0.0.0-8443-1201" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f7435257800 nid=0x5361 runnable [0x00007f73e162a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:724)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:449)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:748)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:559)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:398)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:449)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteChars(OutputBuffer.java:473)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.CharChunk.flushBuffer(CharChunk.java:469)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.CharChunk.append(CharChunk.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.write(CoyoteWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.write(CoyoteWriter.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:240)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at x.y.z.common.web.dispatch.StartPageDispatcherServlet.forward(StartPageDispatcherServlet.java:52)
    at x.y.z.common.web.dispatch.StartPageDispatcherServlet.service(StartPageDispatcherServlet.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at net.anotheria.moskito.web.MoskitoFilter.doFilter(MoskitoFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at net.anotheria.moskito.web.MoskitoFilter.doFilter(MoskitoFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at net.anotheria.moskito.web.filters.JourneyFilter.doFilter(JourneyFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at net.anotheria.moskito.web.filters.MoskitoCommandFilter.doFilter(MoskitoCommandFilter.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at x.y.z.common.web.useragent.TouchScreenDeviceFilter.doFilter(TouchScreenDeviceFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at x.y.z.common.web.LandingPageFilter.doFilter(LandingPageFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at x.y.z.common.web.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

grepping netstat output shows having 817 connections in CLOSE_WAIT and 3 in ESTABLISHED states for this ip.

accesslogs shows:

```
140.206.78.100 [13/Feb/2013:15:20:48 +0100] http--0.0.0.0-8443-364 GET  o1uNdliDOQhJkDnbvXo4RIZ2.undefined 1276 HTTP/1.1 443 / 200 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
140.206.78.100 [13/Feb/2013:15:20:50 +0100] http--0.0.0.0-8443-364 GET  o1uNdliDOQhJkDnbvXo4RIZ2.undefined 1259 HTTP/1.1 443 / 200 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
140.206.78.100 [13/Feb/2013:15:20:51 +0100] http--0.0.0.0-8443-477 GET  o1uNdliDOQhJkDnbvXo4RIZ2.undefined 2991 HTTP/1.1 443 / 200 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
140.206.78.100 [13/Feb/2013:15:20:53 +0100] http--0.0.0.0-8443-428 GET  o1uNdliDOQhJkDnbvXo4RIZ2.undefined 2456 HTTP/1.1 443 / 200 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
140.206.78.100 [13/Feb/2013:15:20:54 +0100] http--0.0.0.0-8443-639 GET  o1uNdliDOQhJkDnbvXo4RIZ2.undefined 1305 HTTP/1.1 443 / 200 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
140.206.78.100 [13/Feb/2013:15:20:54 +0100] http--0.0.0.0-8443-491 GET  o1uNdliDOQhJkDnbvXo4RIZ2.undefined 1326 HTTP/1.1 443 / 200 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
140.206.78.100 [13/Feb/2013:15:20:56 +0100] http--0.0.0.0-8443-491 GET  o1uNdliDOQhJkDnbvXo4RIZ2.undefined 1293 HTTP/1.1 443 / 200 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
140.206.78.100 [13/Feb/2013:15:20:57 +0100] http--0.0.0.0-8443-663 GET  o1uNdliDOQhJkDnbvXo4RIZ2.undefined 1315 HTTP/1.1 443 / 200 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
140.206.78.100 [13/Feb/2013:15:20:59 +0100] http--0.0.0.0-8443-663 GET  o1uNdliDOQhJkDnbvXo4RIZ2.undefined 1277 HTTP/1.1 443 / 200 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
140.206.78.100 [13/Feb/2013:15:21:02 +0100] http--0.0.0.0-8443-225 GET  o1uNdliDOQhJkDnbvXo4RIZ2.undefined 2427 HTTP/1.1 443 / 200 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
1
```

we use Jboss AS 7, java 6/7 (tried both), ubuntu on vm, ssl offloading and loadbalancing with alteon loadbalancer.

PS: 
added netstat sample, three of those:

```
tcp        0      0 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:14186    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:14620    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:13859    ESTABLISHED
```

and 817 of those:

```
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:13233    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:11649    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:11605    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:11892    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:13692    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:11988    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:13055    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:13242    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:13073    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  37960 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:10176    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:14557    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:12288    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:12509    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:11049    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:11839    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:14208    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1  35040 my.public.ip:8443       140.206.78.100:14662    CLOSE_WAIT
```

Comment: Could you add a `netstat` sample?

Comment: @fglez done, pasted some greped ESTABLISHED and CLOSE_WAIT lines. No other states for this ip.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a denial of service attack. Blacklist that client IP address.

Comment: This should be blacklisted on a router as close to the internet as possible (even better if you can get your ISP to blacklist it), not on the web servers themselves.

Comment: The people concerned seem to concentrate on Tomcats somehow. When I put an Apache HTTPD in front of mine, the nuisance abated.

Comment: I would guess it's because of the slowloris vulnerability. CVE-2012-5568

Comment: I would doubt it, because it happens from time to time, and we are able to survive most of it, the threads will go away after some time. Also why would a slowloris attack remain in one browser session?

Comment: @Leon Because they're all coming from the same IP address. What evidence do you have that there is a browser involved at all?

Comment: @Eric: none, but they do use the same http session in one packet. That would be very uncommon for an attacker to stay in same http session (jsession)

Comment: @Leon according to the netstat output you posted you had hundreds of connections in the CLOSE_WAIT state to the same host.  Thats not the same http session. Whether or not it's the same jsession has nothing to do with an attack. They could simply be using curl to do this and storing/resending cookies.

Comment: @Eric: sure, sure. It just _looks_like_ same session from access log.